# ngFor For complicated json

Tags: json, angular, angular7, ngfor

I have following JSON data and using `*ngFor` in Angular 7 need to display data in tabular format.

```
 <table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
        <td>java</td>
        <td>.Net</td>
        <td>Integration</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A1</th>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <th>B1</th>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>200</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>c1</th>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>309</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Here is the JSON**

```
[
   {
       "grade":"A1",
       "data":{
        ".Net" :"6",
        "Java":"7",
        "Integration":"7"
     }

},
{
    "grade":"B1",
       "data":{
        ".Net" :"12",
        "Java":"70",
        "Integration":"56"
     }
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Please see my comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it dynamically, you can create a formatted array having the points in an array.

Try like this:

TS:

```
  data = [
    {
      "grade": "A1",
      "data": {
        ".Net": "6",
        "Java": "7",
        "Integration": "7"
      }

    },
    {
      "grade": "B1",
      "data": {
        ".Net": "12",
        "Java": "70",
        "Integration": "56"
      }
    }
  ]
  formattedData:any = []
  columnHeaders: string[] = []


  ngOnInit() {
    this.columnHeaders = Object.keys(this.data[0].test)

    this.data.forEach(element => {
      let row = {
        grade:element.grade,
        points : Object.keys(element.test).map(key => element.test[key])
      }
      this.formattedData.push(row)
    }); 
  }
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td *ngFor="let item of columnHeaders">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of formattedData">
      <th>{{item.grade}}</th>
      <td *ngFor="let point of item.points">{{point}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to use **keyValue**, don't use the formattedData at all and do this:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td *ngFor="let item of data[0].test | keyvalue">{{item.key}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
      <th>{{item.grade}}</th>
        <td *ngFor="let sub of item.test | keyvalue">{{sub.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is some issue in the loop...the data is repetitive

Comment: Sorry @aba0303, I didn't understand your comment

Comment: Looking into it. Give me 2 minutes

Comment: Changed in ts `points : Object.keys(element.test).map(key => element.test[key])`

Comment: The requirement is that the <th> (i.e java , .net , integration) should also becoming from the json.Currently the data is in table is not as per the JSON

Comment: Okay. Doing that

Comment: Edited the answer, check `<td *ngFor="let item of columnHeaders">{{item}}</td>` and `this.columnHeaders = Object.keys(this.data[0].test)`

Comment: You are welcome.. would you please upvote my answer

Comment: It is not ethical to copy others answers  in the same question :-)

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda You haven't added headers dynamically, I have modified that. Therefore this is not copied, Also I didn't delete my own solution which is similar to your first solution which you changed completely based on Swoox 's comment. And I agree that using keyvalue is better approach than my another solution, therefore I added it with modification

Comment: Ok but if it is better you should add keyvalue pipe before two day ago no

Comment: I didn't because there was already another answer (yours - better one ). But today the one who asked the question commented for some modification, so I showed him in 2 ways.. mine original and also with keyvalue

Comment: When you see better answers do not forget to upvote :-)

Comment: I knew it and your answer is also better one. Upvoted :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your table headers array using one of your `JSON` array object as below.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  thFields: any = [];
  data = [
    {
      "grade": "A1",
      "data": {
        ".Net": "6",
        "Java": "7",
        "Integration": "7"
      }
    },
    {
      "grade": "B1",
      "data": {
        ".Net": "12",
        "Java": "70",
        "Integration": "56"
      }
    }];
    constructor () {
      this.createHeaderFileds();
    }

    createHeaderFileds(): void {
      for (let key in this.data[0].data) {
        this.thFields.push(key);
      }
    }
}
```

**You can do this using above created `thFields` and [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) as follows.**

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
  <td *ngFor="let header of thFields">{{header}}<td>
</tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
      <th>{{item.grade}}</th>
        <td *ngFor="let sub of item.data | keyvalue">{{sub.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Find Working [StackBlitz Demo Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-angular-keyvaluepipe?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Why not use the keyvalue pipe?

Comment: @Swoox Great suggestion. I updated my answer. Thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes @SudarshanaDayananda....almost it has solved my problem...but as you see the data for .Net and Integration for B1 has interchanged and not as per the JSON. (in the stackblitz demo)...Pls help on the same

Comment: Infact I need the <th> also to be dynamic .And as per the working demo the data in table and json doesnt match

Comment: Ok in your JSON array, are all the object containing same keys. it means every object contains **grade** field. as well as in **data** field also containing equal number of subfields like **.Net**, **Java** and **Integration**

Comment: yes , every object contains 'grade', and data field contains equal number on fields (for e.g, there may be 10 'data' fields, but the 10 remain same in all objects)

Comment: You have selected correct answer. any way i updated my stackblitz example. see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
        <th>java</th>
        <th>.Net</th>
        <th>Integration</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let o of obj">
        <th>{{o.grade}}</th>
        <td>{{o.data['.Net']}}</td>
        <td>{{o.data['Java']}}</td>
        <td>{{o.data['Integration']}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```